# intelliJ IDEA generated ant file does not output files

Tags: intellij-idea, ant, kotlin

I have a java project converted automagically to kotlin. Now I generate ant build file for the project, but the variables are undefined:

```
<property name="code.output.dir" value="undefined"/>
<property name="code.testoutput.dir" value="undefined"/>
```

When I change the value to a non existent directory it is not created. And when I create the directory manually the next time the build succeeds the directory is removed.

How do I compile my project properly?

Comment: Related http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-ant.html

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Why do I have to manipulate the ant task, when the build file is auto generated?

Comment: The Ant build script generation in IntelliJ IDEA does not support Kotlin at this time, and there are no plans to add support. Please consider using a different build system, such as Gradle.

Comment: Thanks for information, @yole. I leave this question unanswered, b/c it is Not Implemented Yet.

Comment: It's extremely unlikely that it will ever be implemented.